# After manually setting value to selectpicker option:selected giving all option as selected

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am working on query **select-picker**.
If am looking for **option:selected** on on-change event is is working as expected.
However if I am setting manually select value to select-picker and then looking for **option:selected** it is showing all option as selected in spite of on web page it is showing only set value as selected.

Reference :-

```
var sel = $thisRef.closest('tr').find('.selectpicker');
sel.append($.parseHTML(html));
sel.selectpicker('refresh');  
sel.selectpicker('val', 2);
var option_all = $(sel).find('option:selected').map(function () {
                  alert(sel.text()); // showing alert for each option //expected for only where value = 2
                 }).get().join(', ');
```

Assistance would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Worked as expected